# Good Sample for AWS S3 file transfer Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there is any best sample for xamarin aws s3 server file transfer? I had tried the sample but it is working in native android, not working in xamarin forms. could someone please guide me. Thanks
Any help will be greatly appretiated.

```
       if (file == null)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "No file to upload", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            return;
        }

        var S3Client = S3Utils.S3Client;
        try
        {
            var response = await S3Client.PutObjectAsync(new PutObjectRequest()
            {
                BucketName = Constants.BUCKET_NAME.ToLowerInvariant(),
                FilePath = file.AbsolutePath,
                Key = file.Name
            });

            Toast.MakeText(this, "File uploaded to S3 Bucket", ToastLength.Long).Show();

        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Upload failed, check logs for more information", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            System.Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you should go through their documentation for `Xamarin` and `.Net`

In the [Setting Up the AWS Mobile SDK for .NET and Xamarin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/setup.html), they have given their own samples to refer to!!

Following are the links for each service that they provide for Xamarin

[Cognito Identity](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/CognitoIdentity)

[Cognito Sync](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/CognitoSync)

[Dynamo DB](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/DynamoDB)

[Mobile Analytics](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/MobileAnalytics)

[S3](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/S3)

[SNS](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/SNS)

Also when you check the Using [the S3 Transfer utility docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/s3-integration-transferutility.html)

They have everything you need there to configure your Forms project using Dependency services.

Do not forget to read the [API usage for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/s3-integration-lowlevelapi.html) before you start working with the same

Comment: I had tried s3 sample in the above document but it works on xamarin android, but unable to run the solution in xamarin forms.

Comment: You cannot do it directly in xamarin forms I already told you, you need native implementations using dependency services

Comment: i had done this code using dependency service but the issue exist in xamarin forms project only

Comment: What do you mean issue exist in xamarin forms project can you elaborate?

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/S3 in this sample aws is working perfect.But when i use this code in xamarin forms project it leads to error.System.Aggregate exception. ihad verifed it i think this is xamarin error.

Comment: System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket has been shut down. right now facing this issue

Comment: Are you directly using this code in Xamarin.Forms PCL? or is this a dependency service?

Comment: depedency service.Right now i can able to upload data with small file like text but unable to do it with large file> 1mb

Comment: Issue exist only in xamarin forms,it is working fine on android and c#

Comment: What about iOS?